# What does this len(sys.argv)!=2 does in the following protobuf code?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I am new to protocol buffer and currently working on it. I was checking out the tutorial at the Google's developer tutorial for protobuf. I found out the python program to write data to protocol buffer. Here I don't understand what does this line do. Also to run this does I have to pass any arguments on cmd.(Windows)

```
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
      print "Usage:", sys.argv[0], "ADDRESS_BOOK_FILE"
      sys.exit(-1)
```

This is the following code below to write data.

```
def PromptForAddress(person):
  person.id = int(raw_input("Enter person ID number: "))
  person.name = raw_input("Enter name: ")

  email = raw_input("Enter email address (blank for none): ")
  if email != "":
    person.email = email

  while True:
    number = raw_input("Enter a phone number (or leave blank to finish): ")
    if number == "":
      break

    phone_number = person.phones.add()
    phone_number.number = number

    type = raw_input("Is this a mobile, home, or work phone? ")
    if type == "mobile":
      phone_number.type = addressbook_pb2.Person.MOBILE
    elif type == "home":
      phone_number.type = addressbook_pb2.Person.HOME
    elif type == "work":
      phone_number.type = addressbook_pb2.Person.WORK
    else:
      print "Unknown phone type; leaving as default value."


if len(sys.argv) != 2:
      print "Usage:", sys.argv[0], "ADDRESS_BOOK_FILE"
      sys.exit(-1)
address_book = addressbook_pb2.AddressBook()

# Read the existing address book.
try:
  f = open(sys.argv[1], "rb")
  address_book.ParseFromString(f.read())
  f.close()
except IOError:
  print sys.argv[1] + ": Could not open file.  Creating a new one."

# Add an address.
PromptForAddress(address_book.people.add())

# Write the new address book back to disk.
f = open(sys.argv[1], "wb")
f.write(address_book.SerializeToString())
f.close()
```

Comment: With the len(sys.argv) function you can count the number of arguments passed to the script. so if it is different from 2 the sys will exit with code 255 ( -1 is treated as 255 ) because of 8 bits encoding.

Comment: yes I know that part but please have a look at the program. It says that if len !=2 the it will exit, but at first if no arg is passed then always len won't be equal to 2 so it will always sys.exit().

Comment: Interestingly just running the program should give you a strong hint on your questions.

Comment: This is what I get when I run the file in cmd(windows):               E:\Prototype>python py_read.py
Usage: py_read.py ADDRESS_BOOK_FILE

Comment: Even if I pass an argument at the command line I get the same output. This simply states that the program is getting exit at every execution. Every time the sys.exit(-1) is running.

Answer (score 1):

This part is checking the number of provided parameters. If something is missing, the program exists with an error. More details can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv).

I would recommend switching to a dedicated framework (like [`click`](https://click.palletsprojects.com)) to handle building of CLIs (command line interfaces).

Comment: but when ever I run this code it always exit bu typing the 'print "Usage:", sys.argv[0], "ADDRESS_BOOK_FILE"'

Comment: I don't understand the question probably. Maybe you're running Python 3.x? The code is 2.x compatible.

Comment: No that is not the case as I formatted it fro Python 3 while running it. But at every execution the sys.exit(-1) runs so it terminates the program and other lines after that is not executed.

Comment: @KundanJha are you aware, that ` sys.argv[0]` is the prograqmm itself? so you're setup to supply **exactly** two arguments. If you supply one or three arguments, your programm will fail

Comment: @KundanJha, also if you pass the file name at startup, use `argparse` ist super simple and safe!